# Passing an async Task as Action to method?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have a method used 100+ places that takes in an Action as parameter. I've now introduced a new method that requires awaits and had to be made async. What options do I have for passing that new async Task (previously void) action to the method?

```
// What I need (want) to do

MethodToBeCalled(DoSomething);

// Methods

void MethodToBeCalled(Action action)
{
    // Do Something
}

async Task DoSomething()
{
    await MethodX();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Tried using Func but didn't find a way to get it to work

Comment: note: you don't need the `return Task.CompletedTask;` at the bottom of `DoSomething` - the `async` deals with that for you; in fact, that won't compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot; you would want a `Func<Task>` instead of `Action`, for example an overload:

```cs
await MethodToBeCalledAsync(DoSomething);

async Task MethodToBeCalledAsync(Func<Task> action)
{
    // ...
    await action();
    // ...
}
```

Any attempt to do "sync over async" via `.Wait()`, `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, etc: is dangerous and defeats the entire point of the `async Task` method.

Comment: What if I need to store the action somewhere? Would that mean I'd need a separate property for the Func<Task> and switch on which one is called based on which is set?

Comment: @Zeus you could perhaps just store `Delegate action`, and do `if (action is Action a) { a(); } else if (action is Func<Task> f) { await f(); }` or similar